# White screen before splashscreen

Tags: android, performance

I have an issue with my `SplashScreenActivity`, when I start my application on my phone it shows a white screen for about 0,5 seconds. The `MainActitivy` extends `FragmentActivity` and in the `AndroidManifest` I declare the `SplashScreenActivity` as launcher and portrait mode as `screenOrientation`.

**The code:**

```
public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
    randomSplash();

    Thread splashscreen = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Intent mainScreen = new Intent("com.rm.jkrm.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(mainScreen);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashscreen.start();
}

private void randomSplash(){
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = random.nextInt(4);

    LinearLayout ln = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen);

    switch(i){
    case 1: 
        ln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash1);
        break;
    case 2: 
        ln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash2);
        break;
    case 3: 
        ln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash3);
        break;
    default: 
        ln.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.splash0);
        break;
    }
}
}
```

**XML:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/splashscreen"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: are you doing heavy task on main thread in your MAINACTIVITY?

Comment: probably your `R.drawable.splashXXX` resources are very large and it tooks a lot of time to load them

Comment: I agree with @vmironov

Comment: I changed the images (350kB) to images of 50kB, the white screen appears for only about a quarter second now.

Comment: If you want to see the magic, then set the background image in xml and remove the appropriate code and see it won't take any second to load

Comment: I think I should stick with one image as a SplashScreen because then it loads smooth, thnx.

Comment: Another way could be use Async Task to reduce seconds.

Comment: If its like `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` or `singleTask` for that activity in Manifest then please remove the `launchMode` and see.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To fix white screen on app Start up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up)

Answer (score 1):

```
 Thread splashscreen = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                Intent mainScreen = new Intent("com.rm.jkrm.MAINACTIVITY");
                startActivity(mainScreen);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            } finally {
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    splashscreen.start();
```

this is your problem UI thread to sleep not a very good idea use handler instead
and I think it may cause an exception too.

```
Handler h=new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash_Activity.this,Main_Activity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: Still the same issue occurs, but ty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this two actions in an AsyncTask:

```
setContentView(R.layout.splashscreen);
randomSplash();
```

put the `setContentView` in the doInBackground-method and in the postExecute method you run `randomSplash`.

Answer (score 1):

Change SplashActivity theme in the AndroidManifest.xml file to this.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
```

Comment: Its not about titlebar. its about white splash before splashscreen.