# Android - Launcher Activity showing for one second

Tags: android, android-activity

so, I have a little problem, while opening my app.
I have an "ugly" popup opening for 1-2 sec and then my app goes in.

How exactly can I open my app directly without that 2 sec empty page?

btw - I changed the string of the android:name of my launcher activity to verify that it is this exact activity that is opening empty, and the name changed in the actionbar so it is this activity.

[the picture of the first and "ugly" screen](http://cl.ly/image/3w151D2F0R0h)
<---

here's my manifest code :

```
<application
    android:name=".BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" >

    <activity
        android:name=".UI.activity.HomeActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:launchMode='singleTask'
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyAppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

anyone had this kind of problem before?

thanks a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up

Comment: @Kesh1234 you are a lifesaver!, I've been looking everywhere for a similar question and couldn't find any.. sorry for duplicating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone ever experience this kind of issue like me,

the solution for me was changing the theme of the app to

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

thank you Kesh for relating that question!