# blank screen comes before splash

Tags: android, splash-screen

The main problem is the splash screen appears after 2-3 seconds. Before splash screen a blank layout appears which I don't want. Otherwise it runs fine. Just want to remove the blank layout which appears before the splash page.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();
    private static long SLEEP_TIME = 5; // Sleep for some time

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Removes title bar
        this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);  // Removes notification bar

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Start timer and launch main activity
        IntentLauncher launcher = new IntentLauncher();
        launcher.start();
    }

    private class IntentLauncher extends Thread {

        @Override
        /**
         * Sleep for some time and than start new activity.
         */
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Sleeping
                Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME*1000);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            // Start main activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }

}
```

main layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@drawable/splash"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How To fix white screen on app Start up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up)

Comment: Why splash screens ? What's so good about a screen in your software that does nothing but make the user wait for your app to start ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Generally speaking, splash screens are not recommended for an app but if you really must.

Android will load a blank layout before it loads an activity layout based on the theme you have set for it. The solution is to set the theme of the splash activity to a transparent one.

Create a transparent theme in `res/values/styles.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
      <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
     <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then set the theme in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
...
</activity>
```

Comment: You have update your styles.xml to this <style name="Theme.MyTheme" android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>

Comment: This theme doesn't work with AppCompatActivity, As well as, it doesn't remove the status bar.

Comment: This is not working at all. The app crashes

Answer (score 37):

It's better to use a **Themed background** for your starting activity but if you don't want the blank screen appears before launching main activity you can define your activity like this:

Add `android:windowDisablePreview` to your **AppTheme** in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then set your activity theme in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
...
</activity>
```

P.S: Setting `android:windowDisablePreview` has no effect on your activity background, so you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: disable preview saved me. Thank you

Comment: the app is crashing with this

Comment: android:windowDisablePreview was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: when we press the icon to preview the splash it is taking a little bit time on Icon,

Comment: doesn't work for me

Answer (score 13):

The problem you are facing here is called 'cold start' and it's the time mostly spent in your `Application.onCreate` method, which usually does some initialisations and it might take longer than you wish. You can read here the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/launch-time.html

If this is the case than setting the theme to translucent or disabling preview as others suggested will only apparently solve the issue, because in reality you will try to launch the app and you won't receive any feedback about the fact the you tapped the app icon. You will see your app starting with a delay, which is not a desired UX.

Blank, black or white screen, it really depends on the `android:windowBackground` attribute specified in your main activity theme.
The best you can do, apart from moving some of the initialisations that you probably are doing in your `Application.onCreate` method, is to brand your preview window with a logo as suggested in this post:

https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/Z1Wwainpjhd

You can go further and improve the user experience by animating your logo image in a splash screen, if it's the case, or by designing the preview window in a way that can be smooth transitioned to your main activity content, like described here:

http://saulmm.github.io/avoding-android-cold-starts

Same question is answered correctly here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40482549/7094200 and described in this blog post: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

Answer (score 9):

With support for AppCompatActivity

### res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

GL

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30343050/5279996)

Comment: Awesome bro. Saved my time alot.

Answer (score 6):

Really! the below link work for me!!!!

https://cyrilmottier.com/2013/01/23/android-app-launching-made-gorgeous/

write the separate style in style.xml for your splash screen so that you can co-relate both the screen.

Herein the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Splash" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_final</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the tutorial that I've been looking for! I totally forgot  who wrote.

Answer (score 3):

It' s android features. You can change background color of your blankscreen. Use style:

```
<resources>
<style name="Theme" parent="android:style/Theme" />
<style name="Theme.MainTheme" parent="Theme">
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_drawable</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

then use it in manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="@string/app_name"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MainTheme"
     >
```

Answer (score 3):

I think this is similar to some answers that have been posted above. I still would like to recommend the following Big Nerd Ranch guide on how to create a splash screen the right way because its well illustrated and easy to follow. You should really go there and read it instead of continuing below :).
https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

But in short what it suggests is, at app start you launch an initial splash activity. For this activity you create an XML drawable (`@drawable/background_splash`).

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap
            android:gravity="center"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then you create a theme for splash activity’s and set the drawable you created above as its window background.

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

And then in the manifest you tell the splash activity to use the above theme.

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Finally in your splash activity implement the`onCreate` method like below (thats all the code you need in the activity). This will launch your main activity and finish the splash activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: the bitmap should not be Vector drawable. It will crash on a lot of devices.

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your styles file

```
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```

Comment: This doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed mine by just updating the build tools in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
 <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 </style>
```

If you load image in your splash screen than load Image from your layout,
like below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/color_white">
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivSplash"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/SPLASH_IMAGE"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

Sinle line solution. working perfect in my case;

just add this line in your app theme -

```
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
```