# App halts on black screen before splash screen when app starts

Tags: android

when i try to open app for the second time it gets halt on black screen that loads before splash screen and does not load splash screen
link that i have searched
[blank screen comes before splash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342933/blank-screen-comes-before-splash)

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPrefs prefs;
ImageView ivSplashLogo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG).build())
            .build();

    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);

    Window window = getWindow();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams winParams = window.getAttributes();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        winParams.flags &= ~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS;
    }
    window.setAttributes(winParams);
    window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    prefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    prefs.setCount(0);
    ivSplashLogo = findViewById(R.id.iv_splash_logo);
    latestVersionRequest();
}
```

my gradle file is:

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    multiDexEnabled true
    versionCode 61
    versionName "1.0.61"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }


    }
}
```

Here is style.xml file

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_grey</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_logo</item>

</style>

<style name="KidsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorRed</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#ea7c29</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">@color/darkColorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="tolbar.title" parent="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/solid_black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="BitrateMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">25dp</item>

</style>


<style name="KidsPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/Widget.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item>

</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
    <item name="color">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>


<style name="MyDarkToolbarStyle" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>


<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemTheme">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemThemeWhite">
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/white</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemBackground">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemTheme</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>

<style name="SelectableItemBackgroundWhite">
    <item name="android:theme">@style/SelectableItemThemeWhite</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless</item>
</style>

<style name="OverrideMultipleImageSelectTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/OverrideCustomActionModeStyle</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="OverrideCustomActionModeStyle" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionMode">
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_bottom</item>
</style>


<style name="AppLoginTheme" parent="Theme.AccountKit">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

It does not show any error in logcat

Comment: I prefer to create Application class then put firebase initialization in Application onCreate method then it will not loading on Splash Screen

Comment: read this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application?hl=en

Comment: thanks for your answer but it does not load splash activity at all although splash activity is my launcher activity instead it gets halt on the black screen that shows for a second(in other applications).

Comment: Can you put manifest file

Comment: thanks. but the problem is solved it was facebook sdk that was causing the problem. Now solved.

Answer (score 1):

When you use AppCompatActivity then you have to use proper theme for your activity, which is define in android menifest file. For my app i am using below theme and it`s working fine without showing black screen on starting

```
 <style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
 <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
 <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
 <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
 <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
 <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```

for more detail you can check [here](https://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2016/09/android-black-screen-before-splash.html)

Answer (score 0):

No such issue can be replicated from the code but what i can suggest you to use are following tricks:-

- Make Splash as the launcher activity
- Use Handler to navigate from splash activity to another activity after few seconds
- Use Intent flags as SINGLE_TOP & SINGLE_INSTANCE with it

Comment: thanks for your answer but my point is it does not load splash screen it gets halt on the black screen that shows for a second(in other applications).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple Solutions

1.`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` put this in your Activity style

2. `<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>`
   put this in your Activity style
3. `<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/slash_screen</item>`
   put this in your Activity style
4. `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`

**EDIT**

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
<item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/light_grey</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
<item name="android:actionModeBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

 <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
</style>
```

use this in your style and try

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);   setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    prefs = new SharedPrefs(this);
    prefs.setCount(0);
    ivSplashLogo = findViewById(R.id.iv_splash_logo);
    latestVersionRequest();
}
```

Replace this code with your oncreate

Hope so this will help you

Comment: can you post your style file

Comment: i have added style file and updated my question...please check

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
Move this line after     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: i have tried and i put log also. but it does not load splash activity. if i uninstall the app and reinstall it. it will work perfectly for the first time. but after closing it and opening app for the second time this issue occurrs.

Comment: Please check the oncreate method and replace with your code

Comment: i have tried but still same problem. this only happens on samsung devices. on other devices like oppo etc, it is working fine