# Android White Screen on Before Splash

Tags: java, android, kotlin, splash-screen, launching-application

When Launching android app it shows white screen almost 3 sec. I have added this line of code in style to remove white screen,

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">false</item>
```

It removes white screen but now app launch is taking 3 to 4 sec. How to fix this issue. Kindly help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30342933/blank-screen-comes-before-splash

Answer (score 0):

Move code out of your onCreate/onStart/onResume. All of these methods block the app startup. Instead, launch a background thread/coroutine/task to load your app asynchronously, while displaying a loading page as it loads.