# Why app freezes for some time while the first opening.?

Tags: android, splash-screen

My app freezes for some time while the first opening of the app. From there on app fires up with no time. Why is this happening and any ways to fix this? I have tried adding a Simple Activity with one small image, even then it freezes for the first time.

Comment: You might be doing lot of work in your Application class.

Comment: is it happening after build and run from android studio or anytime?

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up

Comment: Would you give some more data like showing some of your code and what is the image resolution,which device you are testing.

Comment: The app itself freezes, or the process of building the app takes longer?

Comment: @HareshChhelana Thanks for your replay, That solution is only hiding the white screen, even then it takes time to show anything on the screen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a strange issue with newly released Android Studio 2.0 or 2.1. First time of launching application take longer than usual. This issue happens only in debug mode and not effect to your released APK. Also I was suffering this issue and found this solution.

Settings/Preferences→ Build, Execution, Deployment → Instant Run and uncheck Instant Run