# How to prevent blank screen at startup with android view-pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, slider

I'm trying to create a slider in android using a viewpager so followed the tutorial from [developper.android.com](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). 
Now everything works fine, but there is one minor detail that bothers me; every time I launch the app, a white blank screen appear briefly before the actual slides start to appear in the screen:

[image][image]

I think it has something to do with setContentView() method. So how can I show the slides directly at startup and skip the blank screen.

Thanks in advance

Comment: show more code. You may be doing something in non-optimized way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind guys, I found the answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up) of stack overflow, I added this line to my style.xml file and it fixed the problem:

```
<item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
```