# Does including too many import in same file slows the application in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making a react native application which has many screens.So what i am doing is that in app.js file i returned a file named AppNavigator.js in return method.In AppNavigator file i have imported more than 25 screens and all are used in some navigators.I mean that my application includes 6 naviagtor and they are stacknavigator and drawer navigator.I have one stack navigator as primary because it is starting point for my application.That stack has initial Screen as splash screen.But when i start application then splash screen loads after taking too much time.So my question is does including too many imports in same file slows the application? If yes then how can i keep all the navigators in the project structure.I am new to react native development so make my concepts clear.

Answer (score 2):

Well, importing those screens are necessary for navigator to work.

but I must tell you that you have used **only 25 screen**. There are RN apps having over 100 screens.

Personally, I have worked in a project that had 30+ screens into single stack navigator, 
so this can't be your issue.

because at final they are going to bundle into one single file i.e. `index.android.bundle`.
so it doesn't matter where you have written your file and where you are importing it is going to bundle into `index.android.bundle`.

Yes, it will have effect on performance but not much that you can see with your bare eyes.

So, here problem can be

1. **debug** mode.

   try running it in **production** mode(open dev menu -> dev settings -> disable JS Dev mode)

   *or*

   generate **released signed** app
2. white screen before splash for a second

   [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546703/how-to-fix-white-screen-on-app-start-up/34960302#34960302) can be solution

Answer (score 0):

**You can try following:**
- If you're currently on testing mode and if you're debugging js remotely try stopping that first and check the performance.

- Uninstall the app and run following command

  cd (path to project/android folder) && gradlew clean && cd (path to project root folder) && react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res && react-native run-android

the above command will clean all the last builds & clean and clear all the cache and the give new build.

You're good to go!